# How to set the timeout for CompanionDeviceManager.associate()?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

To make a Companion Device association in Android for API 26+, we are supposed to call [`CompanionDeviceManager.associate(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/companion/CompanionDeviceManager#associate)

If the system does not find any devices to pair with, it is supposed to call the [`CompanionDeviceManager.Callback.onFailure(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/companion/CompanionDeviceManager.Callback#onFailure(kotlin.CharSequence)) passed to the association request. The documentation states that one such error case is when the request times out.

How long is this time-out limit, and how can I set it to some value that is convenient for me?

Comment: Did you get your question answered already?

Comment: No. I have not found any info on the topic. :(

Comment: I found no documentation about the timeout at all. Therefore, I just set a timer of 15 seconds by myself. After 15 seconds I tell the user there was no device found. Also, for 15 seconds I deactivate the functionality for the user to start another .associate() call.

Comment: Great minds. I did essentially the same thing.

Comment: @Philip Could you please tell me how you deactivated the functionality? Because when the timeout triggers I don't have any access to disable triggering the CompanionDeviceManager.Callback